# cant insert data into table

Tags: java, mysql, insert

I wrote this code to insert data into tbl_Hotel_Reservation table .. but it's not working ! What is the problem?! can it be in valuse part in insert query? 
person and involved_by are int format !

```
    // DO RESERVATION
    DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy");

    int hotel_id = 0;
    String username = jTextField4.getText();
    String city = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String hotel_name = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String start_temp = jDateChooser1.getDate().toString();

    Date start = parser.parse(start_temp);

    String end_temp = jDateChooser2.getDate().toString();

    Date end = parser.parse(end_temp);

    int person = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());

    try
    {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JEREN","root","");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();

        String insert = "insert into tbl_Hotel_Reservation (start_date,end_date,number_of_person,arranged_by,involved_by) VALUES ('"+start+"','"+end+"',"+person+",'"+username+"',"+hotel_id+");";

        stat.executeUpdate(insert);

        stat.close();
        con.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Reservation is done Successfully!");

    }
    catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e)
    {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error occurred in reservation process");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Users.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for telling us it's not working but not telling us what is happening. How are we supposed to know what it does?

Comment: Meet [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) - his school likes building queries with string concatenation too.

Comment: To avoid Bobby Tables problem also known as SQL-injection use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: use PreparedStatement and do something like this prepStat= conn.prepareStatement(Your String). Now to insert values do this:  prepStat.setString(1, "testName"); and so on (adapt it to your table). And then use prepStat.executeUpdate().

Comment: problem is with date that I input from jDateChooser ..

Comment: Jeren...post the exception stack trace. We can't do anything with what you've told us.

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Jan 01 23:58:55 EET 2014"

Comment: You're trying to format with `M-dd-yyyy`. What don't you understand about the error?

Comment: I am trying to format with yyyy-mm-dd .. but the output of jDateChooser is as Wed Jan 01 23:58:55 EET 2014 ! so I have to change it to yyyy-mm-dd to be able to insert into database . but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Date` object doesn't have a format. A `Date` object simply represents some specific instant in time.

You already have a `Date`. Why are you trying to get its `toString()` value and parse it back to a `Date`?

```
String start_temp = jDateChooser1.getDate().toString();
Date start = parser.parse(start_temp);
```

That doesn't make any sense.

If you're trying to enter the `Date` in the format you have as text into your table, simply format the `Date` object you have.

```
String start_temp = parser.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());
```

If you're trying to enter the `Date` as an SQL timestamp field, use a `PreparedStatement` with one of the `setTime()` or `setTimestamp()` methods.